# What is dot multiplication

Tags: matlab

When multiplying matricies what is the difference when there is a dot there? Can this give different results

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the built-in Matlab function `uniquetol` to obtain the unique values up to some tolerance in the array and ask the length of the returned array.

*Example*

```
A = [1+1e-11 2 3 4 1 2 3]; % generate an array with 4 unique values except for some tolerance
length(uniquetol(A, 1e-10)) % will return 4
```